# Ccxt Probit try to fetch trades: Probit access token expired, call signIn() method

Tags: python, ccxt

I am trying to fetch account private trades on Probit, using the Ccxt library but I have the following error and do not understand why. I checked the documentation and I am unsure on how to resolve the following error message: `AuthenticationError: probit access token expired, call signIn() method`

This is my small code:

```
import ccxt
probit = ccxt.probit({
    'apiKey': probit_api_key,
    'secret': probit_api_secret,
    'enableRatelimit': True
})


if probit.has['fetchMyTrades']:
    probit.fetch_my_trades(symbol='DTX/USDT', since=None, limit=None, params={})
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You literally call

```
if probit.has['fetchMyTrades']:
    probit.sign_in()
    probit.fetch_my_trades(symbol='DTX/USDT', since=None, limit=None, params={})
```

After that call sign_in() every time when `probit.options['expires']` is less than current timestamp (the values are in milliseconds).